# Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed Appium

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, appium

I have just started learning `Appium` testing using **`C#`**. I made simple program using Visual Studio to just open app from Emulator.

When I run my code I am getting this error

> Message: System.UriFormatException : Invalid URI: The Authority/Host
>   could not be parsed. TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is my code

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    private AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
    private DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
    [SetUp]
    public void InItDriver()
    {
        capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.SetCapability("PlatformName", "Android");
        capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "Pixel_API_27:5554");
        capabilities.SetCapability("appPackage", "com.sisapp.in.tulip");
        capabilities.SetCapability("appActivity", "SplashActivity");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new Uri("https:127.0.01:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(driver);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void CloseTest()
    {
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

Note: I did not installed anything like *Appium Server* in my machine.

These packages I have installed in my project. How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: try "https:127.0.01:4723/wd/hub" to "http s://127.0.01:4723/wd/hub" without blank.

Comment: I tried it. But still same issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must **install** and **start**  **Appium server** in your pc. Then you will be able to run appium test.

Steps to install appium server

1. Download and install nodejs from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. install appium server from cmd using:

   `npm install -g appium`

To start appium server:

```
appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 --session-override
```

In your code code instead of **Uri** try to use **URL**. Also change your url as follow:

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("https://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

**Edit:** Above issue is going to solve by this workaround regardless what other issues you are getting :).

Comment: When I am installing Appium Windows10 not allowing me to install it. This is the [https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.12.1](Appium-windows-1.12.1.exe) link(Appium-windows-1.12.1.exe
). Is there any other safe or authorized link is there to download it.

Comment: You must know **Appium server** and **Appium Desktop** are two separate things. Appium Desktop is combination of **Appium Server** and **Appium inspector**. You can install any of them or both as per your requirement.

Comment: to install appium you need to install nodejs then you will be able to install appium server using `npm install -g appium`.

Comment: what was the error showing what you install the **appium-desktop**?

Comment: you can follow [this guide](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-desktop/) to install appium desktop

Comment: Error I am getting is, My Window10 now allowing to install. Saying that this software is not safe.

Comment: It installed now successfully.